# jquery ajax array response handling

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, response

How to handle a array response from .getjson. Following code handles ajax request.

```
function getinfo()
 {
     $query="select field_uname_value,field_uaddress_value,field_uphone_value from {content_type_udetails}";
     $result= db_query($query);
     $i=0;     
     while($item = db_fetch_object($result))
     {
      $info[$i++]=array($item->field_uname_value,$item->field_uaddress_value,$item->field_uphone_value);
     }
     print_r($info);
 }
```

and returns array as follows

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => bharath
            [1] => 12th street ,ram nagar
            [2] => 213124442
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Christina
            [1] => 77,five corner
            [2] => 76874323
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ranjan
            [1] => queen towers, 4th layout
            [2] => 45745747
        )

)
```

but following ajax handling not works. how to get the array response

```
 $.getJSON('/knpgetuserinfo.json&timestamp'+new Date().getTime(), function(data) {
   alert(data[0][0]); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do that, print_r just prints teh array to readable text, you still some key/value separation form in there, and as your using `getJSON` i would say that you use `json_encode()`

```
function getinfo()
    {
        $query="select field_uname_value,field_uaddress_value,field_uphone_value from {content_type_udetails}";
         $result= db_query($query);
         $info = array();
         while($item = db_fetch_object($result))
         {
             $info[] = array(
                 'name' => $item->field_uname_value,
                 'address' => $item->field_uaddress_value,
                 'phone' => $item->field_uphone_value
             );
         }
         echo json_encode($info);
     }
```

and then use javascript like so:

```
$.getJSON('/knpgetuserinfo.json&timestamp'+new Date().getTime(), function(data) {
    $.each(data,function(item){
       //use item.name or item.address here
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing, you need it in JSON format via [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), by replacing:

```
print_r($info);
```

With:

```
echo json_encode($info);
```

The problem is you're not returning the data in a [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSON) format currently, so when jQuery goes to parse, it fails.

Comment: the json_encode returns a string, not an object of any type in PHP, should just be echo'd !

Comment: @RobertPitt - Yup, when I slapped his code in a quick test it reminded me, already updated :)